# How to pass parameter to a callback with no access to the mother function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback

In Javascript I have the following function from an external library:

```
getParentTabId(callback);
```

In other parts of the code it is used like this:

```
var openTab = function(result){
  var parentId = result.Id;
  //opentNewTab is another external function
  openNewTab(parentId, 'https://www.google.com');
}

function handleOnClick(){
  getParentTabId(openTab);
}
```

and that is working. My purpose is to passo to openNewTab a variable as second parameter instead of using a fixed value such as 'https://www.google.com', as follows:

```
var openTab = function(result, url){
  var parentId = result.Id;
  //opentNewTab is another external function
  openNewTab(parentId, url);
}
```

I tried the following:

```
function handleOnClick(){
  var url = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
  getParentTabId(function(result){
    openTab(url, result);
  });
}
```

But it does not work because the callback is not able to see the `url` variable. Taking into account that I cannot modify the getParentTabId function, how would you tackle this issue?

Comment: `But it does not work because the callback is not able to see the url variable` - it is not true. Callback is able to see url variable, because of javascript closure.

Comment: Could it be that you’re switching the `url` and `result` parameters around? openTab expects a `result, url` but you wrote `url, result` in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try declaring a function `getOpenTab` that returns a `openTab` function with a dynamic url:

```
function getOpenTab(url) {
  return function(result) {
    var parentId = result.Id;
    //opentNewTab is another external function
    openNewTab(parentId, url);
  }
}

function handleOnClick() {
  getParentTabId(getOpenTab('www.foo.com'));
}
```

Explanation: You correctly stated that the callback does not "see" the url parameter, because in the implementation of `getParentTabId` the callback is called as `callback(result)`. That's why your callback function has to be created dynamically.

Now, how to create a function with dynamic content? Easy, just make another function that returns your callback function with the needed dynamic parameters.

With an anonymous function the whole things becomes:

```
function handleOnClick() {
  var url = 'www.foo.com';
  getParentTabId(function(result) {
    var parentId = result.Id;
    openNewTab(parentId, url);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In short, what's the difference with my approach?

Comment: I think that at first i misread what your tried already - it seems that the only difference now is the correct implementation of the callback (obtaining the `parentId`, calling `openNewTab(parentId, url)` with the right argument order.